# How to create a adjacency matrix in SPARK scala given two columns and the counts

Tags: scala, apache-spark, adjacency-matrix

I have a spark dataframe with following structure:

```
Entity_1  Entity_2  count
x         y         3
y         z         5
x         z         6
z         x         7
```

I want it to convert into a adjacency matrix, which looks like:

```
    x   y   z
x   0   3   6
y       0   5
z   7       0
```

Is there any package available? I feel like GraphX can be used. 
Please provide the code to make this conversion.

Comment: Why don't you start by indexing the DataFrame's columns first with `StringIndexer` for example ? You can then fill the resulting matrix accordingly.

Comment: @CatalinaChircu I didn't get a chance to try ur suggestion as I could able to accomplish by using spark functions. Please check my answer. Let me know if there any other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer after reading the Spark document, I could accomplish the above by using the following script:

`df.stat.crosstab("Entity_1", "Entity_2")`